# "Failed to get assets" error message 2 weeks now

Tags: phantom, windows

[image: Failed to get assets]

For 2 weeks now, I'm always receiving this error in my Brave browser version of Phantom wallet. Running W11.
The phantom app on iPad shows me no error, runs sans problems.
Have attempted the boilerplate instructions; checked for updated version, tried another connection, etc.

Comment: You will get more help for this in the Phantom Discord. Have you tried removing and readding the extension?

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome... Click on the extension icon, go to manage extensions, enable developer mode. Click on extensions icon again, to the right of Phantom emoji there is a Pin icon then 3 vertical dots. Click on dots , scroll on top where it says "This can read and change data > " then on pop-up, choose "On all sites."